# Is it possible to make the softirq run on the core the user wants?

Tags: network-interface, udp

My system:

- NIC: ConnectX5 MCX516A-CCAT (100GbE NIC)
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- CPU: Intel Xeon Silver 4314 (Dual CPU, 16Core + 16Core)

I'm doing UDP communication using a 100GbE NIC.

However, if the task of the UDP receiver and the software interrupt processing of the NIC are performed in different nodes, the reception speed decreases.

Case 1) When receiving task and NIC's interrupt processing are performed in the same node

[image]
The receive rate is about 4.43 Gbyte/s.
[image: The receive rate is about 4.43 Gbyte/s.]

Case 2) When receiving task and NIC's interrupt processing are performed in different nodes
The receive rate drops to about 3.46 Gbyte/s.
[image: Case 2) When receiving task and NIC's interrupt processing are performed in different nodes]
[image: The receive rate drops to about 3.46 Gbyte/s.]

What should I do to ensure that receive tasks and NIC interrupt handling are always performed on the same node?

Comment: What does *sysctl -a | grep kernel.numa_balancing* tell ?

Comment: And what init system is your system running ?

Comment: And BTW, what answer are you actually looking for : An answer to your question as worded in the title or an answer to your question as worded in the last paragraph ? (two different approaches)

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this interrupt-based? Just disable the interrupts and poll the nic!

Comment: (I say that because you're far into the land, as we discussed under your last question, where connect switches are more expensive than your packet handling, and guess what serving an interrupt implies!)

Comment: by the way, is this dpdk? If so, how fast does the "hello world" example run? It does basically the same as you.

Comment: @MC68020 kernel.numa_balancing is 1,  init system is systemd.

Comment: @MC68020 I'm looking for a way to always satisfy the receive speed of about 4.4Gbyte/s. Now, whenever UDP communication is performed, the softirq is randomly assigned among cores 0 to 31, so if the softirq is executed on a different node than the UDP Receive program, the speed is only 3.4Gbyte/s.

The UDP Receive program and the softirq must both be run on the same node (Core 0~15, or 16~31) to get the 4.4Gbyte/s I want.

For this, I was wondering if it is possible to make a softirq to always be performed on the core the user specifies.

Comment: ACK ! I'll do my best to provide a complete answer tomorrow. As a starting point for sure : You do not want kernel.numa_balancing=1.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Do I have to use DPDK to use polling instead of interrupts? I was trying to use DPDK, but I couldn't install it because of difficulties in setting up the environment.

Comment: so you're still doing a context switch from kernel mode to user mode for every single packet? Solve that, then worry about the <10% difference from CPU non-locality.